# know vs. find out vs. find out about

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I had a stranger reaching out to me via email and I wanted to ask how he knew my email. Do all the following sentences sound good to you?:

> “How did you know my email?”

> “How did you find out about my email?”

> “How did you find out my email?”

I guess the first one does sound natural but I would like to know if the second and third sentences are correct too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these are grammatically correct. The second:

> How did you find out about my email?

suggests asking not how the stranger learned your email, but how he learned that you had email at all, which is not, I think, what you mean.

I think the most natural way to ask the question would be to use"get" as in:

> - How did you get my email?
> - Where did you get my email?
> - From whom did you get my email? [correct but "whom" is underused these days, and so this might seem odd to some]

I would suggest using one of these.

Comment: To me the second is naturally understood as asking "How did you find out about my email message".

Comment: @Peter  Yes it could mean that too.

Comment: @DavidSiegel thanks so much. I didn't know that "find out about my email" could mean something totally different!